# What are the capabilities which SharePoint online modern UI provides to define a custom Header and custom footer

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, theme, communication-site

We want to start a new SharePoint modern communication site collection, and the first step we need to do is to define the site theme mainly the site header and footer.

Currently we have the following design for the header:-

[image]

and the following design for the footer:

[image]

Now based on the built-in capabilities, seems we do not have much options to define such a custom header and a custom footer, so what are the other approaches we can follow to define such a custom header and footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OOTB capabilities**:

1. You can setup header/footer navigation using OOTB settings. You can use different types of header layouts like minimal/compact/standard/extended, menu styles like Mega menu or Cascading menu.
2. You can add links as well as labels in navigation

**References**:

1. [New Site Header Options in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/08/new-site-header-options-are-coming-to-sharepoint-online/)
2. [Customize the navigation on your SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca)

**Custom - SPFx capabilities**:

You can use SPFx application customizer to develop custom header/footer on you site using default placeholders.

**References**:

1. [Use page placeholders from Application Customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions)

**SPFx sample**: [Tenant Global NavBar Application Customizer](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/react-application-tenant-global-navbar)

Comment: so in short we can achieve the Header and Footer requested? is this correct?

Comment: Yes, using SPFx custom development, you can achieve what you mentioned in your question. see the sample link at the bottom for example.